# SQL: Automate the data extraction of categories only that have different character size

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want the following results from the dataset below. I tried using LEFT Function but it will not work as the number of characters are different in every row. I have 741 rows like this but I only need rows with only categories, subcategories are not required.

- Dining->Breakfast
- Dining->Casual_Restaurants
- Entertainment->Movie_Theaters
- Entertainment->Professional_Sports_Venues

DATASET:

Dining->Breakfast

Dining->Breakfast->Casual_Restaurants

Dining->Breakfast->QSR_Restaurants

Dining->Breakfast->QSR_Restaurants->Chick_Fil_A

Dining->Casual_Restaurants

Dining->Casual_Restaurants_PIQonly

Dining->Casual_Restaurants->Applebees

Entertainment->Movie_Theaters

Entertainment->Movie_Theaters->AMC_Theaters

Entertainment->Movie_Theaters->Carmike_Cinema

Entertainment->Professional_Sports_Venues

Entertainment->Professional_Sports_Venues->MLB_Stadiums

Entertainment->Professional_Sports_Venues->MLS_Stadiums

Comment: The trick would be to use char index and find the second ->.
If it does not exist, then return that line.. I'm gathering that is what you want from your desired result... what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please edit your question, post sample data, expected results, your code as formatted text.

Comment: What about `Dining->Casual_Restaurants_PIQonly`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to exclude all records with more than 2 levels from your result:

```
create table #a (cat varchar(500))

insert into #a (cat)
    values  ('Dining->Breakfast')
            ,('Dining->Breakfast->Casual_Restaurants')
            ,('Dining->Breakfast->QSR_Restaurants')
            ,('Dining->Breakfast->QSR_Restaurants->Chick_Fil_A')
            ,('Dining->Casual_Restaurants')
            ,('Dining->Casual_Restaurants_PIQonly')
            ,('Dining->Casual_Restaurants->Applebees')
            ,('Entertainment->Movie_Theaters')
            ,('Entertainment->Movie_Theaters->AMC_Theaters')
            ,('Entertainment->Movie_Theaters->Carmike_Cinema')
            ,('Entertainment->Professional_Sports_Venues')
            ,('Entertainment->Professional_Sports_Venues->MLB_Stadiums')
            ,('Entertainment->Professional_Sports_Venues->MLS_Stadiums')

SELECT  cat
FROM    #a
WHERE   cat NOT LIKE '%->%->%'
```

In the above query we are using a Like pattern to exclude records that have more than 2 levels (identified by having -> appear twice in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The below sample code uses CharIndex to find the start of the second '->' in the string.  To ensure that there is always a second '->' it appends it to the end of the string.

This logic does presume that all categories contain at least 2 levels.  If not then you will need to tweak the logic (possibly using a case statement to test for how many levels there are).

```
DECLARE @val varchar(200) = 'Dining->Breakfast->QSR_Restaurants->Chick_Fil_A'
SELECT LEFT(@val+'->', CHARINDEX('->', @val+'->', CHARINDEX('->', @val+'->', 0) + 2)-1)
```